# how to input data from form to mysql using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

**How to input data using php?**

I already created code to input data from `<form></form>` html to `mysql` using external `php`, but when I try to run it, it looks like this:

[image: when i try to run it]

[image: <code>phpfile</code>]

[image: <code>htmlfile</code>]

Comment: honestly, i am new in php. and i already try to find that problem, but cant explain what is the error type. and my english is not to good.

Comment: are you running it on a server ? if no do it and verify the url

Comment: Your sever need to execute PHP not render it

Comment: Don't open a php file directly in your brower with file:// but run it from the server and browse it. Do never post code as image. That's a pain to read and we can't copy paste anything.

Comment: @Cid, thats work my friend, so what iam doing is pen the file directly, without file:// ..
what a mistake iam doing here, but are u have a fast way how to run it direct.

Comment: I suppose you are using WAMP or LAMP on your computer. Navigate to `http://localhost/yourphpfile.php`

Comment: By the way, you forgot to edit your post in order to remove the screenshots of your code and copy/paste it. That's **really** a pain to read.

Comment: @Cid okay i have try to used `localhost/yourphpfile.php` and thats work. big thanks for you. 
okay i will edit it ASAP

Comment: Please do not add code as a picture.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski okay man, i will edit my questi later, i know that not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand, php codes do not execute by your browser, it is executed on your server, so the first thing you need is a server.

By looking at your URL, I can see you are using `XAMPP`.
Replacing everything before `Resolusi2018` by just `localhost` would do the job.

Put your files into the root directory then access your page by entering 
`localhost/Resolusi2018/root/php/ngetes.php` in your browser.

Comment: You know he is (kinda) using XAMPP right? Else I don't know why he would have XAMPP in his URL. I think he is just not running it properly

Comment: Yeah right, I think she is opening the page directly not from localhost.

Comment: @Luca, yes iam using XAMPP but, iam not running that with the localhost, just direct to the `.html` with direct click from the folder.
okay, here i want to big thanks for u guys, this is look simple but like dangeours. hehehe, and btw iam news in this forum. so i really happy u guys can understand what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think your URL is just wrong.

You are opening the file directly, and not from the localhost.

Try something like this:
`localhost/Resolusi2018/root/php/mgetes.php`

If this is also not working, check if your XAMPP is actually running.

Comment: ohhhh, thats so simple but so dangerous. okay .. now its work.. thansk u my friend.. without u guys, i cant try how my code work

Comment: @TantoWijaya Great to hear it helped you! If any of the answers work, please do not forget to accept one! it helps other people a lot to see what answer worked